# Clojure Repl Unable to resolve symbol for all functions

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have project created with Leiningen and following code in *Core.clj* file:

```
(ns hyperstring.core
(:use [clojure.pprint :only (pprint)])
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
          [clojure.string :as str])
(:import  [java.io File]))

;;read file line by line
(defn read-line-by-line [filepath]
 (with-open [rdr (reader filepath)]
   (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
     (println line))))

;;write to a new file
(defn write-file [filepath]
(with-open [wrtr (writer filepath)]
    (.write wrtr "Line to be written")))
```

and other functions

I enter REPL with *clojure-jack-in* and switch with *(ns hyperstring.core)* to my namespace. Next, I'm trying to start any function in file and get REPL asnswer:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: read-line-by-line in this context
```

**What do I miss?** Maybe some option or deps ?

clojure-1.4.0, Leiningen-2.0, swank-1.4.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(ns some.thing)` does not just switch to a namespace; it creates it.

You should load your functions first using (for example):

`(require 'hyperstring.core)`

or from Slime, `C-c C-k` (slime-compile-and-load-file), `C-c C-p` (slime-repl-set-package) while in core.clj.

Comment: To switch to a loaded namespace use `in-ns`, not `ns`.